# How to define a protocol that lets implementers return their type in a static method?

Tags: swift2

How to define a protocol that lets implementers return their class type in a static method?

```
protocol Insertable {

static func insertObjectWithAttributes(attributes: [String : AnyObject], managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self

}

class Item: NSManagedObject, Insertable {
static func insertObjectWithAttributes(attributes: [String : AnyObject],  managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {

    var item = Item()
    return item  // Error, must return Self
    }
```

If i change Self to Item, the compiler says the class must return Self, and it doesn't work with returning Self either. How can this pattern be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class `final`. Otherwise, your implementation doesn't return `Self`. If someone subclassed Item and added `class Table: Item` then the method should return `Table` not `Item`.

To make it short. Try the following:

```
protocol Insertable {

    static func insertObjectWithAttributes(attributes: [String : AnyObject], managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self

}

final class Item: NSManagedObject, Insertable {
    static func insertObjectWithAttributes(attributes: [String : AnyObject],  managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Item {

        let item = Item()
        return item  // Error, must return Self
    }
}
```